# How to configure Gradle to not run other tasks when running 'gradle test'

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle file that contains the following task, as well as the Java plugin, Appengine plugin, and Jetty plugin:

```
task(copyTestDeps, type: Copy)  {
  from configurations.testRuntime - configurations.runtime
  into 'test-lib'
  def deps = configurations.testRuntime - configurations.runtime
  println '\nAdd these to your classpath from the \'test-lib\' folder: \n' 
  deps.each { println "test-lib/" + it.getName() }
  println '\n'
}
```

When I run `gradle test`, the tests are run and all code is compiled, but this task defined above also runs.

I do not want that task to run, at least not in the beginning but instead at the end, but I'm struggling to see how to tell gradle test to just plain not run this task, as I may end up writing other tasks that I don't want gradle test to run.

I've looked through the documentation for the Java plugin, but I don't see anything in there that would effectively disable this behavior.

How would I configure gradle so that this copyTestDeps task does not run unless I explicitly run `gradle copyTestDeps` from the terminal?  I assume that the documented "doLast" method would work properly in making this run, so let's just focus on stopping `gradle test` from pretending like it owns everything.

Comment: I doubt the task is actually *run* when you execute the test task. It's configured, so the 4 lines of code you added at the end are executed and print stuff. But the actual copy is not done).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the configuration and execution phases. Your task seems to run, but only the print statements are executed; no files will be copied. If you delete directory `test-lib` and do anything with Gradle (e.g. `./gradlew tasks`), you will see the instructions being printed (at the top of the Gradle output) but directory `test-lib` won't exist afterwards.

Change your task definition to:

```
task copyTestDeps(type: Copy)  {
    // Configure how the copy task must behave during execution
    from configurations.testRuntime - configurations.runtime
    into 'test-lib'

    // Run the custom code during execution
    doLast {
        def deps = configurations.testRuntime - configurations.runtime
        println '\nAdd these to your classpath from the \'test-lib\' folder: \n'
        deps.each { println "test-lib/" + it.getName() }
        println '\n'
    }
}
```

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases